# Teradata date subtract issue in PERIOD column

Tags: teradata

I have a teradata table ABC . I have a column in the table which is of `PERIOD` data type ( Name of the column is ef_dtm) . I need to update the starting bound of the period column(subtract it by 1 day) whenever starting bound of the period column is '12/31/9999'. 
I am using the below query . But it is saying

> INVALID Interval Literal.

Can you suggest me an update query?

```
Nonsequenced validtime
update ABC
set ef_dtm = PERIOD(CAST(end(ef_dtm) as Date) -INTERVAL '-1' DAY , end(ef_dtm))
where begin(ef_dtm) = '12/31/9999'
```

Comment: Well, you can't have a Period starting at '12/31/9999' because the end must be greater than the begin. Btw, there's only one reliable way to write a DATE literal: `DATE '9999-12-31'`

Comment: currently in the database period start date is lesser than period end date . Time stamp of period end date is 23:59 . its like this Period start date is 12/31/9999 00:00:00.000 and period end date is 12/31/9999 23:59:00.0000 . What i need is to update Period start date as 12/30/9999 00:00:00.0000 and Period end date can stay as is .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of part `INTERVAL '-1' DAY`

It should be `INTERVAL -'1' DAY` i.e. minus `-` outside the `'1'`

Your query has 2 more problems.

- No need to cast period `begin` to `DATE` as `INTERVAL` arithmetic works on `TIMESTAMP`
- `DATE` literals are wrong. It should be `YYYY-MM-DD`; Moreover it should be `TIMESTAMP` corresponding to period column datatype.

Correct query is as below.

```
nonsequenced validtime
UPDATE ABC
SET ef_dtm = PERIOD(begin(ef_dtm) + INTERVAL -'1' DAY, end(ef_dtm))
WHERE begin(ef_dtm) = TIMESTAMP '1999-12-31 00:00:00.000000';
```

*OR*

```
nonsequenced validtime  
UPDATE ABC
SET ef_dtm = PERIOD(begin(ef_dtm) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, end(ef_dtm))
WHERE begin(ef_dtm) = TIMESTAMP '1999-12-31 00:00:00.000000';
```

> **DEMO**

***Create Table*:**

```
CREATE TABLE ABC ( ef_dtm period(timestamp(6)) AS validtime ) NO PRIMARY INDEX;
```

***Insert Data:***

```
INSERT INTO abc(period (TIMESTAMP '1999-12-31 00:00:00.000000', TIMESTAMP '1999-12-31 23:59:00.000000'));
```

After select

```
ef_dtm
------------------------------------------------------------
('1999-12-31 00:00:00.000000', '1999-12-31 23:59:00.000000')
```

***Update Data:***

```
nonsequenced validtime
UPDATE ABC
SET ef_dtm = PERIOD(begin(ef_dtm) + INTERVAL -'1' DAY, end(ef_dtm))
WHERE begin(ef_dtm) = TIMESTAMP '1999-12-31 00:00:00.000000';
```

After `SELECT`

```
ef_dtm
------------------------------------------------------------
('1999-12-30 00:00:00.000000', '1999-12-31 23:59:00.000000')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation ! It works fine !